# Passing components as props? Compositional vs Higher Order Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating some layout-level components for my React app. As I understand it there are two main design patterns I can utilize - compositional, and higher-order components.

Am I correct in thinking that I have to make use of `props.children` when I want to create a wrapper component in the *compositional* style?

And am I correct in thinking that if I want to, say, pass in two different components (as in the Higher-Order Components example below), I have to make use of the *higher-order component* style?

**Compositional:**

```
const CenteredColumn = props => (
  <div className="columns">
    <div className="column is-8 is-offset-2">{props.children}</div>
  </div>
);
```

**Higher Order Component:**

```
const withTwoColumns = ({ first, second }) => (
  <div className="columns">
    <div className="column">{first}</div>
    <div className="column">{second}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. The **compositional style** allows you to pass children to components ahead of time before they are aware that they have them. So we could do this:

Please see:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

So to the h1 and p tags, the div with a className of 'fancyborder' will cover/wrap/surround them.

**Regarding HOCS**, you are also correct. They are components they receive other component(s) as inputs and render component(s) as the output.

Pardon me not providing code. I used a touch device. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Both work. From the way you're writing it, it's a coding style/hierarchical choice. There are anti-patterns for React, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The way you should you set your layout is by dividing your workflow or proyect structure in presentatational ( Stateless) components and Container components.. The presentationals components will only receive props from their main components while the container components will contain the logic of the applications.

Comment: Hey Christopher, appreciate the response. I'm aware of presentational and container components but I'm working on building some layout-level components that are data-agnostic, just for styling. (Sort of like Bootstrap-React components). They're sort of a different case, I think.